# How to have details of the branch associated with perforce workspace using commands?

Tags: python, perforce

How to retrieve back the stream or branch details associated with workspace using p4 command line option. I currently able to retrieve all data with respect to the workspace via using commnad as follows:

```
p4 client -o C:/myproject
```

And after its execution  i get all the details associated with the workspace "C:/myproject". so, can anybody please help me in figuring it out. I want to retreive stream details by using my workspace only. so please help. Have searched a lot but not able to find how.

Comment: With branch mapping, on a given workspace, the user could be working in multiple branches at once. Plan accordingly

Comment: @XavierT can just tell me which command to be used to retrieve the stream or branch associated with a workspace. i mean something like p4 workspace "xyz" which will show the stream assosiated with workspace "xyz"

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question `p4 client -o` has a line starting with `Stream:`that already contains the stream info ? Is your test workspace pointing on a stream ?

Comment: @XavierT. no i am not getting any line as "Stream:" that is what i am looking for . Rest of other lines like Client: Owner: Host: Description: all are there.. just stream: is missing. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you run:

```
p4 info
```

from within the workspace, it will show you the client and the client stream:

```
User name: testuser
Client name: streams_ws
Client host: Jens-iMac.local
Client root: /Users/jen/workspaces/testing/15.1_streams
Client stream: //streams/dev
Current directory: /Users/jen/workspaces/testing/15.1_streams
```

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I didnt know this point that p4 info from within workspace retreives stream i was trying the same from outside the workspace. thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve stream details by using the workspace only, you can use the 'p4 client -o' command. If the client is truly a streams client, it will show the 'Stream:' field. For example:

*EXAMPLE A*

```
$ p4 -ztag client -o bruno_jam
... Client bruno_jam
... Update 2011/11/07 12:16:05
... Access 2011/03/24 19:15:31
... Owner bruno
... Description Bruno's workspace

... Root C:\P4DemoWorkspaces\bruno_jam
... Options noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
... SubmitOptions submitunchanged
... LineEnd local
... Stream //jam/main
... View0 //jam/main/... //bruno_jam/...


$ p4 client -o bruno_jam | grep "Stream:"
#  Stream:      The stream to which this client's view will be dedicated.
Stream: //jam/main
```

You can also use the 'p4 clients' command to specify which client workspaces are with which stream. For example:

*EXAMPLE B*

```
$ p4 clients -S //jam/dev2.3
Client jc_jam 2011/11/07 root C:\P4DemoWorkspaces\jc_jam 'Joe's workspace '

$ p4 clients -S //pb/2.0-int
Client jc_pb 2011/11/07 root C:\P4DemoWorkspaces\jc_pb 'Joe's workspace for PB '

$ p4 clients -S //jam/main
Client admin_jam-main 2014/09/25 root /home/myadmin/myspaces/admin_jam-main 'Created by admin. '
Client bruno_jam 2011/11/07 root C:\P4DemoWorkspaces\bruno_jam 'Bruno's workspace '
```

REFERENCES

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_clients.html

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html